# Declare a Component[x] Type

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have components on a form and looking for any that are `TMachine` type
Then once I find one I want to get some information from the component.  My Question is: I declare `m`  as `TMachine`  Then try to assign `m := Components[i]`  But will not let me due to `m` being a TMachine type and Components being a Component type.  Any help on how to fix this so I can use the found component as TMachine?

```
procedure TfDeptLayout.bSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  m : TMachine;
  Number,Zone,Dept,Name,Asset,IsPanel,BasicName,FinalLocation,Left,Top : String;
begin
bSave.Visible := false;
for i := ComponentCount -1 downto 0 do
  begin
    if(Components[I] is TMachine) then
      begin
        M := Components[I];
        Number := m.mnNumber;
        Name := m.mnName;
        Asset := m.mnAsset;
        IsPanel := m.mnIsPanel;
        BasicName := m.mnBasicName;
        if checkbox1.Checked then
          FinalLocation := 'shop'
        else
          FinalLocation := 'w';
        Left := inttostr(m.Left);
        top := inttostr(m.Top);
        Zone := myZone;
        Dept := myDept;
        Showmessage('Zone: '+Zone+' Dept: '+Dept
            +'Name : '+Name+' Number: '+Number+' Asset: '+Asset
            +'IsPanel: '+Ispanel+' BasicName: '+BasicName+
            ' FinalLocation : '+FinalLocation+' Left: '+Left+
            +' Top: '+Top);
      end;
  end;
```

Comment: In form methods, I wouldn't use local variable names like `Name`, `Left`, or `Top`.

Comment: @Wouter: That's not a problem: You can use `with Self do` where you need access to the form's properties. <ducks/>

Comment: @UliGerhardt : You can name the form itself "self", add a button called "self", and create a unit called self with some global variables like `name` and `left`, and add that to the uses clause. Russian roulette with the compiler :)

Comment: @Wouter: That sounds like fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to resolve the type mis-match by using a typecast:

```
if(Components[I] is TMachine) then
  begin
    M := TMachine(Components[I]);
```